# Iconic Menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a menu as given in picture[image: Menu].

I am quite confuse where should i start from.

Kindly guide me with some tutorial how to make such menus

Comment: Start by looking into ItemsControl and DataTemplates. Thats all you need to accomplish that menu.

Comment: Do you need to create like this(With images), or just want grid layout?

Comment: @harshanaNarangoda i want to create it with images

Answer (score 1):

If you want your menu to have drop downs like in this image...

[image]

Here is the corresponding Xaml for that item...

```
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding AgeSelectors}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MenuItemPanelTemplate}"  ToolTip="Select which items are included/excluded in the view" Foreground="Wheat">
                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Tango/appointment-new.png" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Age" Foreground="Navy"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          >
                                        <MenuItem.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </MenuItem.Header>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
```

It shows the "Age" button with a drop down where options can be turned on or off with a check box.  The various options like "Last hour", "Last 3 hours" and so on are bound to an observable collection in the View Model.  The Xaml incorporates a WPF Menu that contains menu items, and the user experiences a proper "menu behaviour".

For a Xaml fragment that has no drop down, here's how the "Refresh" item was styled...

```
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" ToolTip="Connect to the net and get news" Foreground="Wheat">
                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                <StackPanel >
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Tango/view-refresh.png" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Refresh" Foreground="Navy"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
```

Others have pointed out that the items can be arranged in a horizontal panel.  In my case, I used a WPF Toolbar to contain the menu items.  It provides the grips and tear-off hints that add to the menu effect.

The Toolbar declaration starts off like this...

```
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Navy" BorderThickness="2,0,2,0">
            <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

The Toolbar can be styled with a gradient background (like the image), or a bitmap background.  And finally, the Xaml for "MenuItemPanelTemplate" is...

```
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MenuItemPanelTemplate">
                        <StackPanel Margin="-20,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

(which I got from here)

So the ultimate choice depends upon if the items should have drop-downs and the overall effect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create a `Style` for the Button that will store Image, probably in the ideal [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx) and text. As a example, you can see my answer:

[WPF C# button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630968/wpf-c-sharp-button-style/17639062#17639062)

Second, you can place all the Buttons in the `WrapPanel` or in the [`ItemsControl`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/).

Example with `WrapPanel`:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button Margin="5">1</Button>
    <Button Margin="5">2</Button>
    <Button Margin="5">3</Button>
    <Button Margin="5">4</Button>
    <Button Margin="5">5</Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

`Output`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Use StacklPanels as below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
    <Button Margin="5">
       <StackPanel Orientation=Vertical>
           <Image source="HomeImageSourcePath"/>
           <TextBlock Text="Home"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Margin="5">
       <StackPanel Orientation=Vertical>
           <Image source="EmployeesImageSourcePath"/>
           <TextBlock Text="Employees"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </Button>  

    ....
    ....

</StackPanel>
```