# Set Properties Dynamically WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties

I have a **property** as: `Button1 System.Windows.Thickness 10,10,10,10`
and a **Button** Name is `Button1`. I'm able to set the same as

`Propertis.Setting.Default.Button1 = _margin;`

I have like many buttons similar to this where my xaml name n property name is  the same, so what I want is to set the margin as dynamically

`Button option = sender as Button;`

`Properties.Settings.Default.option = _margin;`

Is it achievable? If so How?

Comment: What about using a Style for your Button? Or does the value for the thickness change dynamically? Phrases like "many buttons similar to this" indicate normally that you want to define a default style(e.g. thickness, margin, ...). Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630968/wpf-c-sharp-button-style?s=2|2.9116

Comment: No My concept is the button is draggable so when the application is closed the new location should  be saved so that the button opens  in new location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the values stored in Settings are key value pairs, you can set any property which has the same name as of Button control as

```
 Button option = sender as Button;

 Properties.Settings.Default[option.Name] = _margin;
```

Comment: perfect, a piece of cake Thanks :)